# Quadruple Mass Spectrometer - Transition metal detection

Tags: vacuum, mass-spectrometry

We use a QMS in our vacuum chamber, mainly for residual gas analysis. In a recent project I tried using it during the an argon sputtering of carbon infested Ni(111). I got a lot of carbon- hydrate peaks but to my surprise no Ni peaks up-to 200 AMU. I tried firing the Titanium sublimation pump, to saturate the environment with Ti. No peaks again. The QMS has 2 detection mode. one chaneltron and a farady cup. Is there a fundamental reason for not detecting any signals for Ti or Ni?

Comment: Why do you think that highly reactive metals will behave as gases for any length of time? First time hitting the wall and no more free floating atom. Given that Ti sublimation pumps are great for UHV conditions, what do you think the Ti background pressure should be?

Comment: The Ti pump is only a few cementers away from the ionization filament. I find it hard to believe that I don't get any signals from it. not even the slightness peak.

Comment: The vapor pressure of titanium at 1500K is about 2 microTorr. The filament is not on all the time (it only needs to come on to refresh the Ti coating inside the pump), so mostly the equilibrium vapor pressure of titanium in your system (presumably near room temperature) is basically zero.

Comment: Thanks Jon for taking time answering my question. So let me get it right, theoretically these metals should be also detectable using the QMS. is that correct? I know not much about mass spectrometers but I read that the mass/charge ration should be within a certain range so that the ions can accelerate towards the detector, else they don't follow the expected trajectory and fail to reach the detector. This is not the case for the transition metals?